# <TextBlock Text="Random" width="*"/> gives an error

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I know for certain objects, the width can be specified as `width="*"`, so that the width is as large as possible. However when I tried it with TextBlock, it gave an error.

Is there any way of specifying the width of a textblock to be as large as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"*"` is only valid for grid row/column sizing, AFAIK. You want `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`.

UPDATED: Since your comment indicates you're doing this in a ListBox, you also need to set the ListBoxItem's `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `"Stretch"`. Put this in your  element:

```
  <ListBox ...>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ListBox>
```

Comment: HI, tried stretch, it didnt work. I have a listBox (with horizontal alignment) of textblocks, I tried HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" for each TextBlock, it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

The "*" syntax is only supported by RowDefinition and ColumnDefinition in the Grid. You can use "Auto" in XAML to have it automatically determine the best Width/Height. Or in code-behind you can assign the Width/Height to `double.NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing the TextBox within a panel type that autoexpands (i.e. [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx)).  There is a fairly decent example [here](http://www.wpfdude.com/articles/LayoutPanels.aspx).